# How to force a number to be in a range in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, math

In C#, I often have to limit an integer value to a range of values. For example, if an application expects a percentage, an integer from a user input must not be less than zero or more than one hundred. Another example: if there are five web pages which are accessed through `Request.Params["p"]`, I expect a value from 1 to 5, not 0 or 256 or 99999.

I often end by writing a quite ugly code like:

```
page = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(2, page));
```

or even uglier:

```
percentage =
    (inputPercentage < 0 || inputPercentage > 100) ?
    0 :
    inputPercentage;
```

Isn't there a smarter way to do such things within .NET Framework?

I know I can write a general method `int LimitToRange(int value, int inclusiveMinimum, int inlusiveMaximum)` and use it in every project, but maybe there is already a magic method in the framework?

If I need to do it manually, what would be the "best" (ie. less uglier and more fast) way to do what I'm doing in the first example? Something like this?

```
public int LimitToRange(int value, int inclusiveMinimum, int inlusiveMaximum)
{
    if (value >= inclusiveMinimum)
    {
        if (value <= inlusiveMaximum)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return inlusiveMaximum;
    }

    return inclusiveMinimum;
}
```

Comment: It's usually called 'clamp': see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516500/is-there-a-canonical-name-for-a-function-combining-min-and-max and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427477/fastest-way-to-clamp-a-real-fixed-floating-point-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net and so on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I see Mark's answer and raise it by a `this`:

```
public static class InputExtensions
{
    public static int LimitToRange(
        this int value, int inclusiveMinimum, int inclusiveMaximum)
    {
        if (value < inclusiveMinimum) { return inclusiveMinimum; }
        if (value > inclusiveMaximum) { return inclusiveMaximum; }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int userInput = ...;

int result = userInput.LimitToRange(1, 5)
```

See: [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Please note that using extension methods does not have to be necessarily a good thing. It's just another programming tool and it has its uses. Put it in the wrong place or context and you'll end up writing unreadable code.

Comment: Your answer should really be just a comment suggesting improvements to his answer.

Answer (score 74):

This operation is called 'Clamp' and it's usually written like this:

```
public static int Clamp( int value, int min, int max )
{
    return (value < min) ? min : (value > max) ? max : value;
}
```

Comment: I like the name Clamp. Even the Microsoft.Xna.Framework
has a Clamp method :)

Comment: Clamp is the normal name. See the OpenCL specification.

Comment: Ps. This code is more efficient with <= and >=, rather than < and >. :-)

Comment: Add the 'this' and you can use it as an extension method:

public static int Clamp(this int value, int min, int max )
{
    return (value < min) ? min : (value > max) ? max : value;
}

Now you can say: myInt.Clamp(10,50);

Comment: Starting from .NET Standard 2.1 (Core 2.0) there is built in [Math.Clamp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.clamp) method.

Answer (score 37):

A much cleaner method that will work with more than just integers (taken from my own library of shared code):

```
public static T Clamp<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        return min;
    if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        return max;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: That throws a NullReferenceException if `value` is `null`. Better use an IComparer<T> (e.g. `Comparer<T>.Default`) instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx

Comment: As of C#8 you can add notnull after IComparable<T> to avoid the exception pointed out by dtb. 
`public static T Clamp<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>, notnull { // your choice of clamp method body }`

Comment: This is brilliant and very elegant, because it does cover any comparable type (e.g. DateTime) and not just numbers!

Comment: You could add a check to ensure that min is not greater than max.

Comment: Here is a slightly improved version:
https://pastebin.com/0N0PaG6a

Answer (score 18):

I like Guffa's answer, but I am surprised that no one has yet posted a solution using Min/Max.

```
public int LimitInclusive(int value, int min, int max)
{
    return Math.Min(max, Math.Max(value, min));
}
```

Comment: Maybe using `Min` and `Max` each time would have a performance impact?

Comment: Because this only supports integers and types that can be implicitly cast into integers

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It is indeed much faster on my system and should be used if you can deal with working with int data types. I believe this is branchless and will use the math optimized instructions on the processor.

Comment: @OrestisP.: Which is what the OP needed. Not every function your write needs to be able to handle any use case you can think of. That's a great way to waste a bunch of time building an over-engineered mess.

Comment: In all actuality, `Math.Max` (and `Math.Min` also) has 10 overloads; it can handle integers (`int`, `long`, `uint`, etc.) and floating-point (`float`, `double`) as well. So if OP needs to handle floating-point as well, they can overload `LimitInclusive`.

Comment: @Ed S. Agreed, fortunately what you said does not apply in this case.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative way to write your `LimitToRange` function is as follows.

```
public int LimitToRange(int value, int inclusiveMinimum, int inclusiveMaximum)
{
    if (value < inclusiveMinimum) { return inclusiveMinimum; }
    if (value > inclusiveMaximum) { return inclusiveMaximum; }
    return value;
}
```

I think this is a little easier to understand while still being efficient.

Comment: @MainMa: If the value is in range, you have to perform two checks, no matter in which order you put your statements. Performance-wise all answers should be equal.

Comment: Using <= and >= can avoid the second check or a jump on edge cases :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't any method for that built in the framework. I suppose that it was left out because you already have `Min` and `Max`, so you can accomplish it using them.

If you write your own method for it, it doesn't matter much how you write it. If you use `if` statements or the conditional operator `?`, it will still compile to pretty much the same code anyway.

Comment: This sounds like an argument for ceasing all efforts in new and/or updating programming languages if we "already have [the tools]" !! ... we had the tools to write our own Min Max functions so why did they give us those??

Answer (score 3):

To clamp values without giving users any feedback that the value entered by them is wrong, in general, might not be a great idea (IMHO). This might lead to subtle bugs later, which are difficult to debug, especially when min/max values are determined at run time.

Think of this. You have $100 in your bank account, and you want to transfer $150 to your friend. Would you like your banking system to throw an `InsufficientFundsException` or get into a discussion with your friend that you transferred $150 but he received only $100 (assuming the bank clamped the transfer amount to 100 since your did not have sufficient funds)

That being said, you should also look at code contracts.

```
public void MyFunction (Type input)
{
   Contract.Requires(input > SomeReferenceValue);
   Contract.Requires (input < SomeOtherReferencValue);

}
```

This will force the user input to be within the range.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Clamp name. I would suggest the following class

```
public class MathHelper
{
    public static int Clamp (int value,int min,int max)
    {
          // todo - implementation 
    }
    public static float Clamp (float value,float min,float max)
    {
          // todo - implementation 
    }
)
```

or if you want to use generics, then

```
public class MathHelper
{
     public static T Clamp<T> (T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable
     {
         // todo - implementation
         T output = value;
         if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
         {
             return max;
         }
         if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
         {
            return min;
         }
        return  output;
     } 
}
```