# Faster way to do the saturation(n) function?

Tags: c, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

I want to do the saturation function as following:

```
/* Ensure number is >=0 and <=255 */
#define Saturate(n) ((n) > 0 ? ((n) < 255 ? (n) : 255) : 0)
```

If 0 < n < 255, return n; if n <= 0, return 0; if n >= 255, return 255.

I am looking for faster way of doing it. For example, is there any built-in function in c which can be used to reduce the number of instructions?

Comment: Take a look at Trap's answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176602/how-to-force-a-number-to-be-in-a-range-in-c)

Comment: For gcc, there are builtins for certain architectures. However, they are not portable. Which type is n? You reall yshould use functions, not defines. `inline` functions are as good as macros here, but conserve type information and a re easier to debug.

Comment: (n>255)*255 + (1-(n<0 || n>255))*n

Comment: `if (a&(~0xFF)) return (-a)>>31;   else           return a;`