# How to display a signed three bytes hexadecimal output in C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, hex, signed

I want to display a three bytes (signed) in C#.

The code (fragment) I made is:

```
case 3:
   HexadecimalValueRange = SignedValueChecked ?
     string.Format("{0:X6}..{1:X6}", (Int32) minValue, (Int32) maxValue)
    : string.Format("{0:X6}..{1:X6}", (UInt32)minValue, (UInt32)maxValue);
```

But it displays an example negative value as 0xFFC00000 where I would like to see 0xC000000, so with 6 'significant' digits (thus without the leading FF).

Comment: According to [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#XFormatString), the precision specifier *indicates the **minimum** number of digits desired in the resulting string.*  It's not the max number, and it won't clamp the number, as shown in the example: `123456789.ToString("X2") // Displays 75BCD15`.  Try [How to force a number to be in a range in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176602/how-to-force-a-number-to-be-in-a-range-in-c) instead.

Comment: @dbc: I know that it is the minimum number of digits, however clamping the value still would result in leading FF values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading bits of negative number are *significant*, so you can't cut the off with `String.Format` (there is no specifier that let you ignore significant digits, width specify only minimum size and left/right justification).

You can convert the values to 3-byte `uint` to print them the way you want:

```
string.Format("{0,-6:X}",(uint)(int.MaxValue & 0xFFFFFF))
```