# Force a Class's float variable to be within range

Tags: c#

How can I enforce that the variable of a class can be set within a particular numerical range? For example, in my sample code below, I would like to enforce that the user can only be able to set a value between 0.0f to 1.0f for the variable `DownsamplingScale`.

```
public sealed class DownsampleData
{
    public float DownsamplingScale = 0.0f;
}
```

I am not looking for the [Clamping type solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176617/2386113) because I really need to tell the class user that he/she must set a value within the range of **0.0f** to **1.0f** at the time they are using my class (writing code i.e. before compilation).

**There are several ways to deal with the situation during runtime. I need something that informs during/before compilation about the expected range.**

Comment: How would you expect this to work at compile-time if the code that sets the field/property receives a `double` value as its *own* method parameter? Fundamentally, no, there's no way of doing this.

Comment: As long as you're fine with only being able to do this for constants, you can write your own custom Roslyn analyzer. But of course this will quickly fail for non-trivial scenarios like `downsampleData.DownsamplingScale = 1f; downsampleData.DownsamplingScale *= 2`. That sort of thing can't be detected at compile time and must be taken care of with properties.

Comment: Is it an option to use an integer type argument instead, which is scaled to the ranges you want?

Comment: For my interest, why at compile time, I mean the property setter check solution will stop their app once they try to run it

Comment: @Progman: Any datatype will work (including custom struct/class) as long as the values are in the range of `0.0f` to `1.0f`.

Comment: @pm100: If I already know the expected range, why shouldn't I stop someone beforehand instead of waiting for the app to throw error during runtime and then someone has to change code.

Comment: Some languages allow you to define custom numeric types by applying ranges to existing types. C# does not (along with most other languages ultimately derived from C). You *can* define your own custom type that implements arithmetic through operator overloads and offers implicit conversions to/from `float` -- this would not prevent people from "doing it wrong" but it would be at least clearly signal to the user what is expected, and is more amenable to static analysis. A poor man's approach to this is a local alias (`using NormalizedValue = System.Single;`), but that's at best a hint.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts has compile time checks, you could also add fxcop rules maybe

Comment: @pm100: Code Contracts is effectively dead (the chief architect moved on to greener pastures and nobody picked up the slack), there is not and likely never will be a version compatible with .NET Core, for example. FxCop is effectively also dead, but because it's been superseded by Roslyn analyzers (which builds on the same basic idea and rules with a new architecture), already suggested in earlier comments.

Answer (score 1):

> I need something that informs during/before compilation about the expected range.

It's not possible for the compiler to achieve that. The value might be read from a file and that file may not even exist at compile time, e.g.

```
var d = new DownsampleData();
d.DownsamplingScale(float.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file_on_customer_pc_only.dat")));
```

Comment: Don't we have the similar situation in case of `enums`. The values can be set from the provided options only. I basically need something like enum of values between 0.0f to 1.0f and looking for some smart way to do that.

Comment: @skm: "The values can be set from the provided options only." - nope, you can cast any value of the underlying base type to the enum type. For example: `FileMode fm = (FileMode) 1123456;`. So yes, we have a similar situation - in that you can't rely on an enum value actually only being one of the named values.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sure, I am just trying to clarify my requirement. For example, if we have an enum like this for color `enum Color {Red, Green}`, at least the user will come to know that he/she is expected to choose one of these two values at the time of writing the code. Similarly, I want to inform the person at the time of writing the code (i.e. before/during compilation). If someone really wants to break, its ok!  By the way, the variable MUST NOT be of float type. For me, only the values (between `0.0f` to `1.0f`) matters .

Comment: @skm: What if the user receives a parameter of type `Color`? They still don't know that it will be Red or Green, without additional validation. It sounds like you probably want to introduce your own immutable `struct` consisting of a `float` field that's validated on construction. But fundamentally if the value is read from disk somehow (as per Thomas's example) I still don't see how you'd expect that to be handled at compilation-time. *Only* handling compile-time constants is of very limited benefit IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet For sure, I must put a runtime check as well and I will do that. During runtime, I can throw exception etc, I already know how to do that and therefore did not ask question about it. I don't know how can I "also" inform before/during compilation if someone is setting the hard-coded value (e.g. initialization).

Comment: @skm: Your question doesn't say anything about "if someone is setting the hard-coded value". If you *really* only care about constants, you could write a Roslyn analyzer for that. But it will be *really* limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property (or method) where the argument is of an unsigned integer type. You pick the the actual type based on how much precision you need. If you use

```
public byte DownsamplingScaleFactor {get; set;}
```

You will have 256 values to choose from. From the documentation you make it clear that the value `0` means "0%" and `255` means "100%". It will not be possible to use any lower or higher value than that since the chosen type only supports these ranges.

With the type `byte` you will have a precision of 1/256 (ignoring off-by-one issues). If you need higher precision, use any other unsigned integer type like `ushort`, `uint` or `ulong`.

Comment: To play devil's advocate here: you could have much more precision if you used `float`, and indicated that the value `float.MinValue` means 0% and `float.MaxValue` means 100%. Problem solved! ...for some values of "solved". (Of course `float` is even *less* suitable than other types because precision decreases at the outer ends, but you get my point.)